# Is Redis Persistence Enabled?

Tags: redis, persistence

Is there any way to check, from an active session, whether a Redis server has [persistence](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) (e.g. RDB persistence) enabled? The [INFO](http://redis.io/commands/INFO) command does contain a section on persistence, but it is not clear to me whether the values indicate that persistence is turned on.

Answer (score 15):

There are two type of persistance, RDB and AOF.

1. Check is RDB persistence enabled:
   `redis-cli CONFIG GET save`
   RDB persistence **enabled** if it return something like that:

> ```
> 1) "save"
> 2) "900 1 300 10 60 10000"
> ```

RDB persistence **disabled** if you get empty result:

> ```
> 1) "save"
> 2) ""
> ```

2. To check is AOF persistence enabled, invoke:

   `redis-cli CONFIG GET appendonly`

If you get `yes` - it's **enabled**, `no` - **disabled**.

Comment: To understand the meaning of the output like `900 1 300 10 60 10000` check out `save`'s setting description in the example of a `redis.conf` file https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

Answer (score 6):

`INFO` is one way, but you can also use `CONFIG GET` for `save` and `appendonly` to check if persistence is enabled.

As for using `INFO`'s output to understand your persistency settings, this is a little trickier. For AOF, simply check the value of `aof_enabled` under the Persistence section of `INFO`'s output - `0` means that it's disabled. RDB files, OTOH, are used both for snapshotting and backups so `INFO` is less helpful in that context. If you know that no `SAVE`/`BGSAVE` commands have been issued to your instances, periodic changes to the value of `rdb_last_save_time` will indicate that the `save` configuration directive is used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? (e.g. how INFO tells you that persistence is enabled)

Comment: Edited and added the info about `INFO`

Comment: Can you please explain how to use `CONFIG GET` to obtain that information?

Comment: I mean: how to interpret the values

Comment: The documentation about `save`'s values is in the default redis.conf file (http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf).